# Database: Should tables always be normalized and have primary keys?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I have a database storing customer enquiries about products.

The enquiry reference (text), product number (int) and revision number (int) together uniquely identifies a single discussion between sales and customer.

As a result, there are many tables each for a specific detail about a single enquiry, uqniuely idenified by enq, pdt and rev values combined.

The CREATE TABLE does not use any AUTO INCREMENT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY for any field.

My question is, is this database design acceptable?
Should tables always be normalized?

Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use AUTOINCREMENT, but every table should have a PRIMARY KEY of some kind.  A primary key can be a combination of several fields that together identify the record uniquely.

Based on what you've told us, yes, the design is acceptable, provided you explicitly declare the combination of the enquiry reference (text), product number (int) and revision number (int) as a primary key that together uniquely identifies a single discussion.

People sometimes denormalize a database for performance reasons.  If select queries are far more frequent than inserts and updates, and the select query of interest is slow to return because of the number of tables it has to join, then consider denormalizing.

If you supply a specific query that is running slow for you, you'll get lots of specific advice.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, a primary key uniquely identifies every record in the table. So without a primary key you could end up with two (or more) identical records. At that point it would be impossible to update or delete a single record among the identical ones.

Answer (score 2):

Having a `PRIMARY KEY` (or a `UNIQUE` constraint) will, first, ensure that these values are really unique, and, second, will greatly improve the searches for a given enquiry.

A `PRIMARY KEY` implies creating an index over `(enq, pdt, rev)`, and this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    enquiries
WHERE   enq = 'enquiry'
        AND pdt = 'product'
        AND rev = 'revision'
```

will complete in a single index seek.

Without the index, this query will require scanning the whole table, and there is no guarantee that you won't end up with the duplicates.

Unless for very, very, very special conditions (like heavily inserted log tables), you should always have a `PRIMARY KEY` on your tables.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I ALWAYS always have some sort of primary key on all tables, even if it is an auto-incrment number used for nothing else

As to normalization, I think one should strive for normalized tables, but in reality there are many good reasons when a table design is good, but not normalized. This is where the 'theory' of DB design meets the reality - but it is good to know what normalization is, strive for it, and have good reasons when you are deviating from the rules (as opposed to just being ignorant of the rules or worse ignoring good design rules).

Answer (score 0):

These are two questions.
(1) It is not required to have an auto increment key always. It is practical though, since you can use it for easy manipulation of your data. Also having no duplicates is not a must. 
(2) Normalization is a must when you do homework for school, but if things get tough you can break it in order to make your life easier if you do not endanger your data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I am splitting from the herd on this one.  Do NOT make your enquiry reference (text), product number (int) and revision number (int) the primary key.  You indicated the enquiry reference was a text type and did you mean it would be 25 or 50  or 500 characters wide?  If the primary key is made from those fields it will be too wide in my view as it will be appended to every index created for that table increasing the size of every index row by the size of the three fields and any table which needs to use a foreign key back to this table will also need the three fields.

Make the three fields a unique index.  Place an auto-increment value as the primary key and make it the clustered index.  The tables which will link back to this master table will have a small footprint in memory to link the data from table one to table two.

As far as normalized goes it does not matter, normalized or not, if your data is only a few thousand rows, or even 50,000 or 500,000.  When the data starts getting bigger than the available RAM cache then it is an issue.

Design a view to present the data to the application to fulfill the business rule.  Design stored procedures to accept data to store.  Design the table stucture to meet the response time in the SLA.  If you have to normalize or denormalize or patrtition or index or get a bigger server to meet the SLA the app will never know because you are always supplying the data via the view which meets the business rule.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in normalization theory that deals with whether a table should have a simple or compound primary key.  Believe it or not, the concept of "primary key" is not a component of the relational model of data.

Having said that, tables should nearly always be defined with a primary key.  The primary key need not be a single column, and it need not be filled in by an autoincrement.    In your case, it could be the three columns that taken together uniquely identify an enquiry.

If a table has no declared primary key, it could end up with duplicate rows.  A table with duplicate rows represents a bag of tuples, not a set of tuples.  Once you are dealing with bags instead of sets, the results predicted by the relational model need not apply.  That is why preventing duplicate rows is so important.